# Angular. Looking for help on solving issue with sync call used with AuthGuard and directive

Tags: angular, asynchronous, directive, auth-guard

I'm looking for a solution to issue I have with my project.
I have http call to get `userPermissions` and I have two places where I'm using it:

1. Auth guard on route
2. Directive in component template

There's a situation when both occur (loading route with auth guard that loads child component with directive) and I'm looking for a solution to make just one http call if needed rather than do call for each. Is there any "simple" way of doing it without redux?

Below you can find example code, it's not exactly same but will give an idea what I'm trying to do.

user.service.ts

```
export class UserService {
  userPermissions: string[];

  constructor(private userApi: UserApi) {}

  getUserPermissions(): Promise<string[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.userPermissions) {
        resolve(this.userPermissions);
      } else {
        this.userApi.getCurrentUser()
          .subscribe((user) => {
            this.userPermissions = user.permissions;
            resolve(this.userPermission);
          }, (err) => {
             reject(err);
          });
      }
    });

  }
}
```

some.component.ts

```
@Component({
  template: `
     <div appAuth [roles]="['read', 'write']" #myAuth="appAuth"
          *ngIf="myAuth.hasAllRoles()">...</div>
  `
})
```

auth.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'appAuth'
})
export class AppAuth {
  @Input() roles: string[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  async hasAllRoles() {
    const userPermissions = await this.userService.getUserPermissions();
    let guard = true;

    this.roles.forEach(role => {
      if (this.userPermissions.indexOf(role) === -1) {
        guard = false;
        break;
      }
    });

    return guard;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'my-component', canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { roles: ['write'] }, component: MyComponent }
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

auth.guard.ts

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.userService.getUserPermissions()
        .then(((userPermissions: string[]) => {
          if (route.data.roles) {
            let guard = true;

            route.data.roles.forEach(role => {
              if (userPermissions.indexOf(role) === -1) {
                guard = false;
                break;
              }
            });
            resolve(guard);
          } else {
            resolve(true);
          }
        });
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems weird to me, if the user is already authenticated to visit the route, why is it making the same exact call in the component?

Comment: One call for what? You must authenticate and get data right? You're doing it right.

Comment: I think you are already avoiding multiple API calls, in your service, your first check is to see if `user permissions` exist, if not only then you make the API call. If its done in the Guard, a new call should not go in the Directive I believe.

Comment: problem is that it might do one call to userService. getUserPermissions from Auth Guard which will call http request, and before response will call it'll call from directive because of async call and this is calling another http request, because userPermissions are not set yet.